# How to deal with holiday leave/sickness when on retainer?

Tags: retainer, maintenance

When a retainer is set for I.T. services; how should I deal with sickness and holiday leave?

i.e. If a service requires me to attend it within 3 hours; and i'm abroad or quite sick; what would be the best method to inform the client or prepare them for such situations?

This is a question i'm thinking about before forming retainer based structure for my business.

Answer (score 2):

For holidays, just email the client in advance to give them sufficient notice, and don't charge your retainer during that period. If you are sick, let the client know ASAP and again don't charge the retainer for that period (although if the client pays well enough, you might want to remain available even when you're sick).

Answer (score 0):

Mention the most honest reason why you can't make it to the said appointment/job and then just state a short apology. For Holiday leaves, as user45623 mentioned, inform your employer in advance. Share your calendar when possible so that your client/s have an idea of what your schedule looks like.

During sickness, if you are able, offer to work from home. If not, just send them an email, or a quick call/voice message. If you aren't able to provide notice, have someone do it for you. Family/friend/spouse. Anyone. Providing notice shows sincerity and integrity and is certainly better than just going AWOL. Do not charge for work that wasn't done on schedule.